# Ajax call in jQuery - uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'error' of null

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call using the below jQuery.

But I can see in Chrome, i'm getting uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'error' of null. So this stops the class ('success') getting added. Any idea why it's doing this? Do I somehow need to declare 'error'??

```
function submitForm(formData) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'mailer.php',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 7000,
    success: function(data) {
        $("form #form_ajax").removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? "error" : "success")
        .html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');

        if ($('form #form_ajax').hasClass('success')) {
            setTimeout("$('form #form_ajax').fadeOut('fast')", 5000);
        }
    },

     error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('form #form_ajax').removeClass().addClass('error')
            .html('<p>There was an ' + errorThrown + 'error due to a ' + textStatus + ' condition.</p>').fadeIn('fast');
    },

    complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {
        $('form')[0].reset();
    }
});
};
```

Thanks...

Comment: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Line 9

Comment: FB.provide('JSON',{stringify:function(a){if(window.Prototype&&Object.toJSON){return Object.toJSON(a);}else return JSON.stringify(a);},parse:function(a){return JSON.parse(a);},flatten:function(c){var a={};for(var b in c)if(c.hasOwnProperty(b)){var d=c[b];if(null===d||undefined===d){continue;}else if(typeof d=='string'){a[b]=d;}else a[b]=FB.JSON.stringify(d);}return a;}});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your code to :

```
    success: function(data) {
 if ( data.error)  alert(data.error);
  alert(data);
     $("form #form_ajax").rem...
```

and tell me the alert msg (theres 2)

EDIT : its not make any sense:

do this : [image]

Comment: ok , now :  `complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);alert(status);...`

Comment: after ` success: alert('1');` after error : alert('2');after complete: alert('3')`

Comment: I can still only see 'uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'error' of null'

Comment: change `if ($('form #form_ajax').hasClass('success')) {
            setTimeout("$('form #form_ajax').fadeOut('fast')", 5000);` to `if ($('form #form_ajax').hasClass('success')) {
            setTimeout($('form #form_ajax').fadeOut('fast'), 5000);`...no `"`

Comment: after the `alert('1');` write  : `if (data) alert('y'); else alert('n');`

Comment: thats it : your `data`  is null . the server program doesnt return any object.

Comment: this is a new question which you need to paste a new code. select the one who helped you the most and check his answer and then ask a new question with new code from the server.

Comment: Now fixed, I simply omitted  "dataType: 'json'," and it worked. Bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

`data` is `null`, probably because your server didn't send any JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response SLaks, is it obvious why this might be happening? Anything I can try?