# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need some help with this code, I have found some similar issues:

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550795/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined)

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312479/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined)

[Ajax call in jQuery - uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'error' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868981/ajax-call-in-jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-error-of-null)

but still not working,  I'm using jquery (.ajax) to send and recieve data to the server (php), when I use localhost at url in .ajax function, it works fine and receives the data that I need, but when I change the url for the ip of the server it shows: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property *"some value"* of undefined"

Jquery code:

```
$(document).on("ready",inicio);

function inicio(){



  /*Change pages events*/
  var buttonscan;
  buttonscan = $('#button_scan');
  buttonscan.on("click",solicitardatos);



}

function solicitardatos(){
           var idscan = "001";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                //with localhost works fine, this is the ip of my cpu when testing from
                //other device 192.168.0.101
                url: "http://192.168.0.101/server/info.php?jsoncallback=?",
                data: {datos:idscan},
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {


                $('#button_scan').hide();
                $('#page1').hide();
                $('#page2').show(); 


                $('#pl').html(data[0].pl);                 
                $('#name').html(data[0].name);


            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Error... " + textStatus + "        " + errorThrown);
                alert("Error... " + textStatus + "        " + errorThrown);
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

}

And this is the PHP server file (info.php)

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require("conexion.php");


$id = $_POST['datos']; 

/*Here is all the sql statements, and the mysqli query*/

while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($peticion)) {

    $resultado[] = array("pl"=>$fila['pl'],"name"=>$fila['name']);  
}



mysqli_close($conexion);
//echo json_encode($resultado);
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($resultado) . ');';

?>
```

So when I use the url setting (localhost) it works, when I change to the server ip (192.168.0.101) it stops working and shows:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pl' of undefined"

, I know that the ip it is working because when I copy 192.168.0.101/server/info.php at my browser it doesn't shows any error

Thanks,

Now I have used an external server, which is in cloud, and it works if I use a constant $id = "001" at info.php, but when I removed that constant and put $id = $_POST['datos'] ,is empty again, so I think there is something wrong when sending the data

Comment: The structure of your URL looks odd. Why 2 question marks? Is there some difference, perhaps, between the versions of the php code running on the two different server machines, or some difference in the data?

Comment: I might be picking at straws here, but this seems out of the ordinary, at least for me `');';` - did you try removing the extra `;` such as `')';`?

Comment: What have you in the `data`variable in your success callback? It could be an explicit error instead of your data like MySQL permission denied from your IP

Comment: Also, check the HTTP error code of the Ajax call using the network tab in the console (F12) or using soft like Fiddler : http://fiddler2.com/

Comment: And finally, try to call manually the URL in a new browser tab. There are some browser plugins permitting to send POST variables in order to test your web page.

Comment: @MikeW The 2 questions marks itis because I'm using jsonp http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ or http://revolucion.mobi/2013/04/12/login-en-servidores-externos-con-phonegap/ (it is in spanish)

Comment: @Fred this is an example http://www.7bberries.com/pregunta/7447/como-conectar-app-con-mysql-remota-phonegap ; the firsts '  ' are for joining both variables and the seconds '. .' are for the variable

Comment: @jagudel Thanks for the links. Have you tried what `mishik` gave as an answer below? Plus, what I think could be a **WILD GUESS**, is that, in `$('#pl').html(data[0].pl);` there's a `.pl`. In **LINUX** that's a **PERL** extension/executable and it could very well be misinterpreted and causing a conflict. Try changing all **pl** text to something other than that. Again, just picking at straws. I don't know what else could be causing this mi amigo.

Comment: @jagudel Another thing I found out of place is `dataType: 'json'`. Why is it under `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {`? Shouldn't that be inside `$.ajax({` in `function solicitardatos(){`?

Comment: @jagudel If my comment about `dataType: 'json'` being outside your function, just thought about something. Does your data contain any characters with **accents** such as **ñ - ó - Í** etc.?

Comment: @sdespont when I use localhost data has: [object Object] with the data of the query, pl and name; but when I use the ip, data it's empty: and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pl' of undefined"

Comment: @sdespont I used fiddler2.com and this is what I got: for ip:     GET http://192.168.0.104/server/info.php?jsoncallback=jQuery20005893237302079797_1371247676001&datos=001&_=1371247676002 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.104
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost/myapp/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8

Comment: @sdespont and for localhost POST http://localhost/server/info.php?jsoncallback=jQuery200020826240652240813_1371247816530 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 9
Accept: text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest


datos=001, Why when I use the ip, it seems that the method is GET and not POST? could it be the problem?

Comment: @sdespont I have done it manually, with http://192.168.0.104/server/info.php, using a constant variable instead of $id = $_POST['datos'] I use $id ="001" and it returns the data that I need

Comment: @Fred , I've tried it but with no success, the .pl it is because when ajax its success, data returns as an array with all the data of the query, so I need the .pl to access the value of pl and the .name to acces the value of name from data; dataType: 'json' it is inside .ajax({}), althought I put it under data: {datos:idscan}, but no success, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found some part of the issue, when it sends the data, it was sending them as Get, so I changed both .ajax function and info.php

Jquery code

```
function solicitardatos(){
  $.ajax({
                type: 'get',                
                url: "http://192.168.0.101/server/info.php?jsoncallback=?",
                data: {datos:idscan},
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                   ...

             });
}
```

Php

```
 <?php 
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');

    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    require("conexion.php");


if (isset ($_GET['datos'])) { 
$id = $_GET['datos']; 

    /*Here is all the sql statements, and the mysqli query*/

    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($peticion)) {

        $resultado[] = array("pl"=>$fila['pl'],"name"=>$fila['name']);  
    }
  } else {}  


    mysqli_close($conexion);

    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($resultado) . ');';

    ?>
```

I'm not sure why it was sending data as get, but with these changes it is now running , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things to fix:

PHP:

```
< header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
> header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "http://192.168.0.101/server/info.php?jsoncallback=?",
    data: {datos:idscan},
    + contentType : "application/json"
    + dataType: "json"
    cache: false,
```

Comment: When I use contentType : "application/json" it prompts the same issue and no data